# package.json changes not taken into account

Tags: angular, npm, ionic2

I used to have the following in my package.json file :

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.0-next"
```

For some compatibility issue, I have to put it to the following :

"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",

1- I run 'npm update' but it does not update it

2- I've tried to delete node_modules and do 'npm install' but it stays with 0-next version

3- I've tried npm install -g angularfire2@^5.0.0-rc.4 , I don't get any error, but then when I try 'npm list angularfire2' I still see that I have 0-next

4- When I do 'npm outdated' I still see 0-next in the wanted column

What is wrong with my thing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want specific version of the package remove the caret (^) sign. For explanation see: [What's the difference between tilde(~) and caret(^) in package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/whats-the-difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json?rq=1)

Also: https://bytearcher.com/articles/semver-explained-why-theres-a-caret-in-my-package-json/